# Unit of Work with Repository having Generic methods

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6

We are using EF with DB first, and we are not planning to create Repository classes per table. Instead, we will have repository classes representing modules, which internally might interact with multiple tables.

The code which I have started writing is something like this:

```
public class ModuleRepository
{
    public void GetModules()
    {
        using (IUnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            //Get the specific DBSet
            var dbTable = uow.GetDbSet<Customer>();
            var dbTable1 = uow.GetDbSet<Supplier>();
            //do whatever you want to do.

            //call save changes to commit
            uow.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}


class UnitOfWork: IUnitOfWork
{
    private DbContext _context;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        _context = new DbContext("");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public DbSet<T> GetDbSet<T>() where T:class
    {
        DbSet<T> entities = _context.Set<T>();
        return entities;
    }
}


public interface IUnitOfWork: IDisposable
{
    void SaveChanges();
    DbSet<T> GetDbSet<T>() where T : class;
}
```

In SaveChanges I will have the `_context.SaveChanges()` to commit the changes to the DB.

This is I guess one way to do this.

Another possible way could be:

1. create a generic base repository class. Each module repository will have a list of these repository classes.
2. uow class
3. UOW Manager -> will pass list of base repositories to say a method Setup. This UOW Manager will create a UOW with a context, and this UOW will be passed to each repository - effectively all repository having the same context.

I think code wise it will work, though not sure which one is the right approach or there could be some better approach.

Also in any of these two scenarios, how to achieve unit testing? Any ideas around this?

Comment: While this question is a bit broad, your design has leaky abstractions that are leaking implementation concerns. EF is an implementation concern. The initial idea about using modules was a good start, but started to stray when it exposed the DbSets

Comment: But this code will be in repository layer , separate to Business Layer...I think i can write one more IRepository/Repository over DbSet , but will that be useful in this scenario ?